# How to really identify if LOG4J is not included as a dependency?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, apache-karaf

In my work it was detected by Scanner tool that our application was using Log4j vulnerable version (The famous RCE Vulnerability log4j-core version <= 2.17.0) and it was very very hard to detect because even if we ran mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose that dependency would not be shown.

After hours of checking each direct dependency that was declared in the main pom.xml we found out of the following:

There is a direct dependency:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.ops4j.pax.logging</groupId>
<artifactId>pax-logging-log4j2</artifactId>
<version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

If we open pax-logging-log4j2.pom we can see that it is adding log4j-core with provided scope:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It turns out that this transitive dependency which has a provided scope doesn't get detected by mvn dependency:tree goal, I even did a test with a Simple project that only adds pax-logging-log4j2 as dependency and the tree output is the following:

```
com.ram:testdependencies:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
\- org.ops4j.pax.logging:pax-logging-log4j2:jar:2.0.5:compile
   +- org.ops4j.pax.logging:pax-logging-api:jar:2.0.5:compile
   |  +- (org.osgi:osgi.core:jar:7.0.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   |  \- (org.osgi:osgi.cmpn:jar:7.0.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
   +- org.osgi:osgi.core:jar:7.0.0:compile
   \- org.osgi:osgi.cmpn:jar:7.0.0:compile
```

As we can see there is no occurrence of log4j-core dependency even if it is added inside pax-logging-log4j2. How can then we easily detect if some dependency is really being used or not if mvn dependency tree doesn't display everything even if -Dverbose is being specified? What I know about provided scoped dependencies is that they are used to compile and not at runtime (these are provided by the actual running environment, for example servlet api is provided by Tomcat), even so I really don't understand how the log4j-core jar inside this artifact end up being used and therefore picked up by the Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

The [`pax-logging-log4j2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2) artifact is a fat jar, which also includes the classes from `log4j-core`.

There is no universal way to detect fat jars: in this case the original `log4j-core` POM file is included in the `META-INF/maven` folder, but this is not always the case.

The authors of fat jars use various tricks to declare their "dependencies". One of them is adding the dependencies in the `provided` scope (which normally means something entirely different).

In your specific case (cf. [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-log4j2/2.0.5)):

- `log4j-api` is a dependency that must be provided by the runtime environment (IMHO `osgi.core` and `osgi.cmpn` should also be in this scope),
- `log4j-core` is does not need to be provided, because it is included in the jar file.